Issue with MultiThreading in Java: File Not Moved to Archive and Duplicate Kafka Messages
Body:
I am using Java's WatchService to monitor directories for newly created files. Once a file is detected, a thread from a thread pool processes the file with the following steps:

Read the content of the file.

Send the content to a Kafka producer.

Move the processed file to an "Archive" folder.
The code works as expected most of the time, but occasionally, I encounter the following issues:

A few files are processed but not moved to the "Archive" folder.

The content of the same file is sent multiple times to the Kafka producer.
Simplified version of my code:


WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
Paths.get("watched_directory").register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

while (true) {
    WatchKey key = watchService.take();
    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
        if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
            Path filePath = Paths.get("watched_directory").resolve((Path) event.context());
            threadPool.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    // Read file content
                    String content = Files.readString(filePath);

                    // Send to Kafka
                    kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("topic", content));

                    // Move file to archive
                    Files.move(filePath, Paths.get("archive_directory").resolve(filePath.getFileName()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    key.reset();
}

Questions:

What could cause files to remain in the "watched_directory" instead of being moved to the "Archive" folder?
How can I ensure that the same file content is sent only once to Kafka?

Any guidance or recommendations to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!
